# React rerender specific components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a controller, which renders a Table and action buttons.
The Table has Row childs, with checkboxes. This is my render func:

```
render() {
        <div>
            <Table items={this.props.items}></Table>
            <Actions selectedItems={_.filter(this.props.items, i => i.selected)}
        </div>
}
```

By checking each row, I update the item in the list with a 'selected' property.
But now, If I want to change the selected indication, I have to rerender all the container, including the table.
How can I do that without rendering the whole table? (Only render the FloatingActions)

this is my redux mapping:

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to have left some of the details out of your question.  You should take a look at the [`shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to see if you can short-circuit the re-rendering when it's not applicable to the `Table` items (e.g. if the selected props hasn't change).

Comment: Is that the only way to selectively rerender the component? Do I always have to programmatically check by the properties change?

Answer (score -1):

You should use react `key` property and give each row a unique key.
In this case React calls the render method of Table but only re-renders the changed row in the DOM.
Take a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: I have a key property. The issue is that I need to rerender only part of the component. The best way is to use the shouldcomponentupdate?